# two divs z-index overrides childs z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

How come the higher z-index of a parent for a child gets overridden by another parent?

The child `topInner` inside `top` gets overridden by `bottom` z-index. Is not z-index inherited?

I'll provide a code snippet here.

```
<style>
.top {
    width:300px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:blue;
     z-index:30;  
}

    .topInner {
        width: 300px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: green;
        z-index: 30;
        text-align:center;
    }

.bottom {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

```
<div class="main">
<div class="top">TOP
    <div class="topInner">Inner</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: Very good article about test cases with z-indexes: http://aplus.rs/lab/z-pos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divs should have position other than `static` for `z-index` to work.

working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xCsU2/)